# NFS - one file hanging ls

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd, nfs

I have an NFS share hosted on FreeBSD 11.0.1, and a mounted on "trusty tahr" Ubuntu 14.04.

From time to time, there is a single file which is unlistable on the Ubuntu client, but looks perfectly ordinary on the NFS host. find, ls, and the like, all hang when listing this file. The easiest way I have found to identify the correct file is to do a "find"; at some point the find on Ubuntu will hang. I look at the last file before it hung (hanged?), then run a similar find on the BSD side - identify the file after the last one that worked, that's the problem.

The file can be moved (to a different directory), and the problem moves with it. Rebooting the client does not help - the "poisoned" file will still cause the same problem after the reboot. Copying the file leaves the original poisoned, the copy will be perfectly listable/readable.

If I delete the file, the problem will go away for a while, then come back on another file.

dmesg says: [Mon Mar 20 14:11:10 2017] nfs: server  not responding, still trying

---

additional:
I've statted the file (on the BSD side, of course), and there seems to be very little unusual about them (these were taken at different times):

```
stat -x Weekly-15456
  File: "Weekly-15456"
  Size: 15019589632  FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0640/-rw-r-----)         Uid: (  109/   (109))  Gid: (   26/mailnull)
Device: 175,462094506   Inode: 2009    Links: 1
Access: Mon Mar 20 12:24:26 2017
Modify: Mon Mar 20 12:53:11 2017
Change: Mon Mar 20 13:26:57 2017

stat -x ./Daily-17581
  File: "./Daily-17581"
  Size: 401325300    FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0640/-rw-r-----)         Uid: (  109/   (109))  Gid: (   26/mailnull)
Device: 175,462094506   Inode: 8196    Links: 1
Access: Tue Mar 21 01:06:52 2017
Modify: Tue Mar 21 01:10:40 2017
Change: Tue Mar 21 01:10:40 2017
```

Comment: Any more info on the particular file?

Comment: @Kusalananda as per additional section in question. If there's any other info I can provide, let me know